# How to update my inventory stock from an input value

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

First, my english is so bad, if you can't understand me fell free to ask me again.
I'm trying to do an inventory project, basically i have a "Product" table where i keep all my products and a "ProductExit" table to register the quantity of products that i sold. What i want to do is decrease my stock value in my Product table using the "Quantity" value of my ExitProduct table.

Product table/class:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BarCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
    }
```

ProductExit table/class

```
public class ProductExit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Products Product { get; set; }
    public List<Products> ProductCollection { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I used entity framework to create the database connection and scaffolding to create views for every table.

My controller method to create a new Product exit:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ProductId,Quantity")] ProductExit productExit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ProductExit.Add(productExit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ProductosId = new SelectList(db.Product, "Id", "Name", productExit.ProductId);
        return View(productExit);
    }
```

My view:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>MovimientoEntrada</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductId, "ProductId", 
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProductId", null, htmlAttributes: new { 
@class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId, "", new { 
@class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class 
= "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = 
new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { 
@class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The problem is that i can't find a way to decrease the "Stock" value using the user input in my ProductExit view.

Comment: you have tagged sql-server but post a solution using .. is that .net? You should use user stored procedures from your code to handle the tsql code. This will allow you to pass parameters to the database, and let the database handle the code to reduce your quantities. This will make it so the data guys can help you. Currently it is difficult for most of the sql community to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just:

```
HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ProductId,Quantity")] ProductExit productExit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ProductExit.Add(productExit);
            var product = db.Product.Find(productExit.ProductId):
            product.Stock -= productExit.Quantity;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ProductosId = new SelectList(db.Product, "Id", "Name", productExit.ProductId);
        return View(productExit);
    }
```